# Are Cookies left by a page in IE visible to pages browsed in Chrome Frame (and vis-versa)?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-frame

Among other things, I'm trying to track whether users who START our web app with IE, then install Chrome Frame, continue using it or "disappear" (i.e., don't get Chrome Frame installed and start the app again).

One way to do that is with tracking cookies such as Google Analytics, IF the cookies are 'shared' b/t IE and IE+ChromeFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Chromium project (the open source base for Chrome and CF) IE handles all of the network/cookies/history and CF piggy backs.

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/differences-between-chrome-and-chrome-frame#TOC-NETWORK-STACK